# Start python server and Vue front end at boot

Tags: python-3, cron, node.js

I'm trying to have my raspberry pi start a python server with connected Vue.js frontend at startup.

Right now i'm using crontab with the following configuration:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/Desktop/server-client/server/launcher.sh >> /home/pi/Desktop/server-client/server/logs/log.txt 2>&1
@reboot sh /home/pi/Desktop/server-client/client/launcher.sh >> /home/pi/Desktop/server-client/client/logs/log.txt 2>&1
```

the `launcher.sh`in the server folder is a simple `python3 app.py` while the launcher in the client folder is `npm run dev`

When i reboot the rpi only the server starts while the front end doesn't, i'm thinking that it may be because by running `python3` the rpi stays stuck running the server and doesn't start the `npm run dev` process but i'm not sure (trying to avoid this is the reason i have 2 different @reboot instead of a single one and a unified launcher)

I have a flask server written in python with a vue.js frontend developed using npm. To start the server i use python3 app.py while t ostart the frontend i use npm run dev (this builds the frontend dependencies and serves it on a port). I wanted to start them both at startup so i set up a cron job, when i restart the rpi only the python3 command is executed but not the npm run dev one, i'm looking for a way to start them both automatically at startup (they work if i open 2 terminals and start them manually).

How can i make sure that both the python server and the Vue.js front end start when the rpi is rebooted?

Comment: What is a "*python server*"? Python is a programming language. And what client do you talk about? What does `npm run dev` mean?

Comment: @Ingo I have a flask server written in python with a vue.js frontend developed using npm. To start the server i use ```python3 app.py``` while t ostart the frontend i use ```npm run dev``` (this builds the frontend dependencies and serves it on a port).
I wanted to start them both at startup so i set up a cron job, when i restart the rpi only the ```python3``` command is executed but not the ```npm run dev``` one, i'm looking for a way to start them both automatically at startup (they work if i open 2 terminals and start them manually)

Comment: It is important information to understand your question that you missed to add. I have done it for you.